# Some pocket challenges

Tags: lateral-thinking

A "pocket challenge" is a short puzzle where you don't need any complicated process nor writing material and, some times, not even a great knowledge. That's what I like to call them... Here are some I use to dare other people with:

> **1.** A skyscraper windows cleaner were cleaning the windows of the 25th floor when he tripped and fell. He didn't have any security rope nor harness and nothing stopped him from falling. However, he didn't have any injures. How could that happen??

> **2.** A police man saw a truck driver going in the opposite direction on a one way street and didn't tell him anything nor chasing him to arrest (or at least give him a ticket). Why??

> **3.** A woman gave birth to two kids at October 15th 2008 at 01:30 PM. They were not twins. How is that possible?

> **4.** A New York detective heard a testimony about the suspect in a crime: he were playing poker with some friends at 55 Crime Street, apartment 23. He went there, broke into the apartment and saw a truck driver, a fireman, a doctor and a private investigator playing poker. Without any delay and without saying anything, he arrested the fireman. How did he know?

Can you answer them all?

Comment: For 1, technically the ground stopped him from falling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably quite a lot of possibilities for each but I think the ones you are looking for are

1.

> He was cleaning them from inside, so when he fell he simply fell on the floor

2. 

> The driver of the truck is walking, meaning he can go down the street. It’s never mentioned whether he is driving the truck or not.

3. 

> She gave birth to more than 2, meaning they are not twins they are triplets (or quadruplets etc)

4..

> The fireman was the only male, everyone else was female so it had to be the fireman

Comment: You nailed them all... :)